# VirtualPathProvider not working in IIS7

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I am working on a VirtualPathProvider application. It works fine in Visual Studio but I get a 404 error when testing in IIS7.

I have created a simple website in .Net4 classic mode on http://localhost:101/ and the URL i am accessing to test VirtualPathProvider is http://localhost:101/article

You can download the code from http://88.208.236.165/HS/HSTest.zip

Here are screenshots from the error and running app.

[image: Error in IIS7]

[image: Works in VS]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under IIS7, maybe you should try to add this to your web.config:

```
 <system.webServer>
   ...
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" ... />
   ...
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: @UsmanAkram So then why is this marked as the answer? Did it work for you or not?